# what does the 'up{}' syntax mean?

Tags: syntax, prometheus, grafana-templating

i've been working on some prometheus templating and whenever i look at other examples of templating i keep encountering this command:

`$jobs = label_values(job)`

`$instance = up{job=~"$jobs"}`

i understand that $jobs is a variable being created, but i have next to no clue what the up command is doing. I've looked online and i can't really narrow down the search enough for a generic word like 'up' haha

my best guess is that it makes the `$instance` variable equal only to cases where job is similar to jobs? i'm really not sure

any help would clarify a bunch. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Jobs and instances](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/jobs_instances/) Prometheus documentation:

> When Prometheus scrapes a target, it attaches some labels
>   automatically to the scraped time series which serve to identify the
>   scraped target:
>
> ```
> job: The configured job name that the target belongs to.
> instance: The <host>:<port> part of the target's URL that was scraped.
> ```
>
> If either of these labels are already present in the scraped data, the
>   behavior depends on the `honor_labels` configuration option.
>
> For each instance scrape, Prometheus stores a sample in the following
>   time series:
>
> ```
> up{job="<job-name>", instance="<instance-id>"}: 1 if the instance is healthy, i.e. reachable, or 0 if the scrape failed.
> ```
>
> The `up` time series is useful for instance availability monitoring.